# DelayedJob Job instance treats all passed in objects as nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have been wrestling with DelayedJob for the last day and a half.  I'm trying to create a simple Job class that accepts a large string and an ActiveRecord object.  But no matter what I pass in to the Job when enqueing it, it is treated as nil.  I've tried many different strategies to make this work; I have tried passing in just the id of the ActiveRecord object (treated as nil), I've tried adding an initializer to the Job object (rather than having it inherit from an instance of Struct)...nothing works.

I've simplified my job class into something ridiculous, and it still doesn't work:

```
class SimpleJob < Struct.new(:owner_id)
  def perform
    @owner = Owner.find(owner_id)
    puts @owner.full_name
  end
end
```

And in my controller:

```
def test_job
  Delayed::Job.enqueue(SimpleJob.new(@owner.id))
  redirect_to :action => 'index', :controller => 'owner'
end
```

The error is, of course, that Owner can't be found with an id of nil (before you might ask, yes, @owner is instantiated and working; a before_filter ensures this).

I'm using Rails 2.3.5, DelayedJob version 2.0.7.  My Job object is located in the libs folder, if that makes a difference.

Is there some part of the configuration I'm missing?

Comment: on line 1, owner_id is a symbol whereas on line 3, its a plain string, not mentioned anywhere in the code (if these are the only references for owner_id in your code).  may be that's the reason, @owner returns nil.

Comment: Noob question - but what does "class SimpleJob < Struct.new(:owner_id)" do - extend a struct with an object/struct that has one instance var, owner_id - perhaps ?

Answer (score 0):

Your call to delayed job is setup correctly. The first thing to check is that @owner.id is not nil to start with as its more then likely that its the issue

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the DB, in the table delayed_jobs, and check if the object are correctly serialized.

bye